# How to use Text.Printf on entire lists

Tags: list, haskell, printf

How can I use printf with a specific format like `printf "%d %d\n"` on a list ?
For example, `printf "%d %d %d\n", [1, 2, 3]`

My idea was to create a string based on the list that I want to print using a separate function and parse it to `printf`. The problem is I can't get printf to treat the list elements as separate arguments. What am I missing ?

Comment: Do you actually need `printf`? Tell us more about your actual goal. ("Use `printf` on a list" is a plan, not a goal.) Perhaps `unwords . map show` is enough for you.

Comment: I want to print a list of floats as text with `\n` at the end and the numbers must be in the "%+.2f" form.

Comment: @BillMack The most simple thing to do is apply printf to each member of your list individually, and then splice all those short strings together. Something like `intercalate " " (map (printf "%+.2f") [1, 2, 3 :: Float])`

Comment: Yes, this was I was looking for ! Thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelSteele `intercalate " "` is better spelled `unwords`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You split the task into several smaller ones. You write function that handles a single `Double`:

```
show2Decimals :: Double -> String
show2Decimals x = printf "%+.2f" x
```

Afterwards, you can use standard functions to map all your numbers in your list and splice the resulting strings together:

```
showDoubleList :: [Double] -> String
showDoubleList xs = unlines (map show2Decimals xs)
```